# User service granularity levels

Tags: transactions, pyethapp, pending-transactions

Is it possible to fire up event handlers upon transaction creation/confirmation? In [this](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Making-a-User-Service:-Tutorial) tutorial two event handlers are used **on_start()** and **on_block()**.

Is it possible to have a finer level of granularity; handlers that manage transaction creation and confirmation?

Following, this [this](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/develop/examples/urlfetcher.py) example it also seems possible to execute code outside of the blockchain.

Would it be possible to create a handler that invokes a system call upon transaction confirmation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating eth\_newFilter topic listeners with Python](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/creating-eth-newfilter-topic-listeners-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you only have the two `hooks` you mention above: `on_start()` and `on_block()`, beyond that you'll need to experiment with what's possible.  There's very little documentation on the User Service functionality, **but** all the source is there to learn from.

Comment: I only need to check whether a contract executed or not. I'm not sure how much I can do from those hooks

Comment: You can check if a contracted executed by looking up the receipt hash it'll return.  You don't need the user service for that

Comment: Ok, I'll read up on that. My end goal is to be able to launch a syscall depending of the outcome of a transaction.