# Cannot catch every event (logs) from contract - catch a couple of random events instead

Tags: json-rpc, events, python, testrpc, filters

My contract has a transaction which fires an event. I **was able to catch every event** when I was sending transactions manually.

But now I'm sending 100 transactions in cycle and get only 2..5 events. Yes, randomly - which puzzles me the most. I get a **random quantity of events** and **random last event caught** every time I run my code. Please see the console output below.

Tried to add a pause between transactions. The longer the pause the more events are caught. This puzzles me too - don't understand why this matters for events.

#### My .sol contract

```
contract Example {

    uint32 public value;

    event ValueSet(uint);

    function setValue(uint32 val) {
        value = val;
        ValueSet(val);
    }

}
```

#### My python code (sorry for the long code - was afraid to mess it up shortening)

```
class MyContract:

    address = ""
    filter = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = EthJsonRpc('127.0.0.1', 8545)

    def deploy(self):

        # get contract address
        compiled = '6060604052610.....' # shortening it here.
        contract_tx = self.c.create_contract(self.c.eth_coinbase(), compiled, gas=3000000)
        self.address = self.c.get_contract_address(contract_tx)

        # set new filter
        params = {
            "fromBlock": "0x01",
            "address": self.address
        }
        self.filter = str(self.new_filter(params))


    def send_transaction(self, foo, value):
        tx = self.c.call_with_transaction(self.c.eth_coinbase(), self.address, foo, value)
        return tx

    def new_filter(self, params):
        return self.c.eth_newFilter(params)

    def listen(self):
        return self.c.eth_getFilterLogs(self.filter)



def main():
    my_contract = MyContract()
    my_contract.deploy()

    #sending transactions which trigger events 
    for i in range(100):
        my_contract.send_transaction('setValue(uint32)', [i])
        time.sleep(1) # the more time the more events are caught 

    # retrieve all logs from the filter
    logs = my_contract.listen()

    print repr(logs)
    print "Quantity of events: " + str(len(logs))
    if logs:
        print "Data: " + str(int(logs[-1]['data'], 16))
```

#### Console output

```
[
   {
      u'type':u'mined',
      u'blockHash':u'0xac739ae0feac68eae0cddb5216ef64c7931821cf26db327c85bd3da16f947f44',
      u'transactionHash':u'0x4d2465e9b978a275cca63fb9129a5da8f7a9dcc9b2c6e8b717ecf734be7ab950',
      u'data':u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026',
      u'topics':[
         u'0x012c78e2b84325878b1bd9d250d772cfe5bda7722d795f45036fa5e1e6e303fc'
      ],
      u'blockNumber':u'0x0223',
      u'address':u'0x9062a6b9299af4bdb535a5ecdbfeb8a28e6cf4c1',
      u'logIndex':u'0x00',
      u'transactionIndex':u'0x0'
   },
   {
      u'type':u'mined',
      u'blockHash':u'0x1014603151080201cc26990c6b4f1dd01a5b65545b19a570a01c9ad11532c7f2',
      u'transactionHash':u'0xe79af54c765368e73e3c9ca996de667e43363e92856ca234459633fda86c77ca',
      u'data':u'0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f',
      u'topics':[
         u'0x012c78e2b84325878b1bd9d250d772cfe5bda7722d795f45036fa5e1e6e303fc'
      ],
      u'blockNumber':u'0x025c',
      u'address':u'0x9062a6b9299af4bdb535a5ecdbfeb8a28e6cf4c1',
      u'logIndex':u'0x00',
      u'transactionIndex':u'0x0'
   }
]
Quantity of events: 2
Data: 95
```

#### Related

[How to list transactions from account address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/how-to-list-transactions-from-account-address)

[How can I create a listener for new transaction with Ethereum RPC calls?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/how-can-i-create-a-listener-for-new-transaction-with-ethereum-rpc-calls/3783#3783)

[Creating eth_newFilter topic listeners with Python](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/creating-eth-newfilter-topic-listeners-with-python)

#### Why asking

I'm trying to write a code which will save contract event to a database in "live" mode (catch new events) and in "retrospective" mode (retrieve all contract events). And just want to understand how events work.

I'm using ethjsonrpc with testrpc (Ethereumjs).

Thank you very much!

Comment: testrpc was started with no parameters.

Comment: What testrpc release are you using? Events are not acutally supported until [v0.2.0 release](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/8). Use a classic client like geth in the meanwhile.

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao for a working example of extracting the events.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus - I am using events there and they are working

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone I'm using EthereumJS TestRPC v2.1.0. I need to test 10 000 transactions, so I need something faster then geth (or can I run some virtual blockchain with geth?)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thank you! And thank you for your beautiful code of [event listener](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/creating-eth-newfilter-topic-listeners-with-python)

Comment: More up-to-date https://github.com/websauna/websauna.wallet/blob/feat/ethereum-3/websauna/wallet/ethereum/contractlistener.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to add **receipt = self.c.eth_getTransactionReceipt(tx)**. I guess it insures that the transaction is mined.

Now it catches all 100 events.

I've also tried to add a timer after every transaction. 5 seconds after every transaction was enough to catch all events. But eth_getTransactionReceipt works much faster (couple of seconds for all 100 transactions).

Can anybody please explain this? What the code would look like for the production blockchain?

```
    def send_transaction(self, foo, value):
        tx = self.c.call_with_transaction(self.c.eth_coinbase(), self.address, foo, value)
        receipt = self.c.eth_getTransactionReceipt(tx)
        return tx
```